# How to search specific column that contain "text" and delete all row not containing search

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Below VBA code is to find text and delete row. But it is searching based on the whole sheet.

How to I make it to only **search "specific column"** with the text array listed and **delete the rows that contain text**.

Based on the below code, it is search the whole sheet which I do not want.

```
Sub DeleteSystemMessage()
    Dim varList As Variant
    Dim varQP As Variant
    Dim lngarrCounter As Long
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'delete system message
    varList = VBA.Array("XXXXXX", vbTextCompare)

    For lngarrCounter = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
        With Sheet1.UsedRange
            Set rngFound = .Find( _
                                What:=varList(lngarrCounter), _
                                Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)

            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address

                If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDelete = rngFound
                Else
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                End If

                Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)

                Do Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                    Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Next lngarrCounter

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: _How to I make it to only search specific column with the text array and delete the columns that does not contain text._ - please clarify the following: you need to search through ONE column (e.g. Col. D), and delete all the rest of columns on the sheet, or you just mistyped and actually you need to delete **rows**?

Comment: I have edited my question. Is searching the column with the array text. 

If column contain text in column, it will delete the whole row

Comment: Change `With Sheet1.UsedRange` to `With Sheet1.Usedrange.Columns(1)` - that'll isolate the search to the first column in the used range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your search code like this it will only search in the column "A".

```
Set rngFound = Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").Find( _
                            What:=varList(lngarrCounter), _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
```

Comment: good, can you flag the answer as accepted then to close the question.